# Trying to get property of non-object with Twitter response

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to retrieve some info from the response I get from [Twitter's mention method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline)

```
    $mentions = $cb->statuses_mentionsTimeline();
    foreach ($mentions as $mention) {
        echo $mention->id_str .'<br />';  //Line #18
        $urls = $mention->entities->urls;
        foreach($urls as $url)
            echo $url->expanded_url .'  &  ';
        echo '<br />';

    }
```

I got the output as expected, but these errors are printed after the result:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\path_to_file.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\path_to_file.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\path_to_file.php on line 19
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\path_to_file.php on line 20

Comment: Try `var_dump($mention);` just before line #18 and see what it comes up with. Either the method returns NULLs or something every now and then, or the API you are using uses associative arrays instead of objects. Try `$mention['id_str']` if that is so.

Comment: @Aurel300 The `var_dump()` returns an object. Twitter's API returns an `array of objects` as [the response example suggested](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) and I'm trying to loop through them. `$mention['id_str']` returned this error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.

Comment: That does not make much sense ... Hm, does it throw the errors at every single iteration? Or is it just a couple of times in a larger number of successful results?

Comment: @Aurel300 This is interesting. It appears that it goes through the first iteration perfectly, throw the errors and stops.

Comment: I would expect the `var_dump` to produce different output on the erroneous iteration then?

Comment: @Aurel300 Couldn't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. The iterations are working just fine. But the errors are thrown **after** the iterations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48744/discussion-between-aurel300-and-iturki)